# UITextField changes large numbers when inputted

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I noticed something weird in one of my applications and for some really reason, if I submit a small number, say 1,000,000,000, it will function normally but if I submit a large number, say 12,345,678,987,654,321, in this case it was 2147483647.  So i set up a simple app that would just take the number and make it a label's text by

```
var theNum = textField.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().intValue
numLabel.text = "\(theNum)"
```

Now for smaller numbers it work but big numbers like the one above it doesn't.  I should say that I am transferring the variables between views in case that has something to do with it. Also, I know the above code is in Swift but it does the same thing in Objective C. This is really messing with me because I can't find any reason that it would do this so all help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The max value of a signed 32-bit integer is 2147483647...

Comment: So is it possible to make it a different type of integer that can hold higher numbers?

Comment: Sorry for that being a stupid question I am new to all of this

Comment: You can declare a 64-bit signed integer as `Int64`, or unsigned as `UInt64`, but that still only gets you about 18 or 19 digits of precision.

Comment: What would be the difference between signed and unsigned?

Comment: Skip the integer conversion. You don't seem to use it. Just do `numLabel.text = textField.text`

Comment: I know I don't use it for this but I just took the other code away to show as an example for the question.  I actually need it to be an integer for the real code

Comment: `Int64` can have values from -9e18 to +9e18, whereas `UInt64` can have values from 0 to 1.8e19

Comment: Thanks, the only problem with that now is that it says UInt64 does not have a member named 'bridgeToObjectiveC()'  I need to use that to convert the number into a double.

Comment: `UInt64` would refer to the type in Obj.C, not in Swift. You could try substituting `intValue` for `longValue` or `longLongValue` or `doubleValue`, depending on your needs.

Comment: How would I do that without using bridgeToObjectiveC()?

Comment: Well, what does `textField.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().longLongValue` give you when you enter a number <= `9223372036854775807`?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem it's just how would I declare the variable on the other view as a longLong?  Right now I have to do `var theNum: Int = 0` for the data to transfer.  Does that make sense?

Comment: `var theNum: UInt64 = 0`

Comment: @user3386109 I need it to be a longLong

Comment: Try `var theNum: Int64 = 0`

Comment: I already have.  I know that making it a double from the start will work although it uses Scientific notation and has .0 after every whole numbers which is unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

To hold some very large numbers or numbers with high precision you should use the `NSDecimalNumber` class. Note this is a class, not a primitive, you need to allocate it, call a `stringValue` to get the string and to do operations on it you again need to use methods. A short example:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:textField.text];
textField.text = number.stringValue;
number = [number decimalNumberByAdding:[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:10]];
```